# This service implements '2' contracts. InvalidOperationException

Tags: wcf, contracts

I have a WCF service project that I am trying to get up and running on my local development machine.

When I hit the .SVC from IE8 running in Cassini it works no problem.

When I hit the .SVC from IE8 running in IIS I get the following server error.

**This service implements '2' contracts. To use WebScriptServiceHostFactory, you must implement one contract per service. If you must use multiple contracts, please use a regular ServiceHost.**

I would appear I have an issue with my IIS configuration. I have a co-worker that has the project running through IIS on his machine and we have gone through and matched our Windows Features lists to be sure we have the same IIS and WWW features installed in Windows 7.

I have also re-registered aspnet with IIS for 4.0 with no change in the error.

Comment: I downloaded IIS Express to see if the service with the multiple contracts would run and they do! At this point I am at a total loss as to why the service throws the above error when running in IIS on my development box.

Comment: It appears the IIS Express solution was a stop gap because as of this morning my services with multiple contracts no longer work even in IIS Express. So now I am completely at a loss. I also have deployed the service project on other machines in my office that are using them as an application through IIS 7.5 and those other machines work without issue so at this point I can't explain why the services with multiple service contracts don't work on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the a reason why works in Cassini and not in IIS7 is that Cassini emulates IIS6 and there have been a significant number of changes to website configuration between IIS6 and IIS7.  You should most definitely install and use IIS Express 7.5 as your integrated development web host the instead of the default Cassini browser.

Now, you've checked your features but have you checked your IIS7 configuration?  Are you sure that the site is running in the correct (.NET 4) app pool.  Have you also ensure that it is running in the correct mode (Integrated).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have indeed checked the app pool and mode. I am using the ASP.NET 4.0 app pool which is defaulted to integration mode.

Comment: I did finally install IIS Express and it is working so I am sticking with it. I hope I don't see the same issue when we finally deploy to production, but for now my super agrees that IIS Express is legitimate for testing so I don't need to get my installed IIS working right now. Thanks for the help I am marking this the answer.